# Device pixel ratio without the BuildContext

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to make [resolution resolution-aware images](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images#resolution-aware) (BitmapDescriptor)

```dart
static Future<BitmapDescriptor> makeBitmapDescriptor(
      String path, BuildContext context) {
    return BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
      ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio,
      path,
    );
  }
```

& for that I need the **devicePixelRatio**, is there a way to get it without the `BuildContext`  & `MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fromWindow` like this:

```
MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).devicePixelRatio;
```

Comment: thanks is it as precise ? Why use one or the other ? : ) Does it work on mobile ?

Comment: yes it is accurate, and yes it is work on mobile.

Comment: the same you can get directly from `WidgetsBinding.instance.window.devicePixelRatio` - no need for `MediaQueryData`

Comment: `View.of(context).devicePixelRatio` is now the only non-deprecated way.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
import 'dart:ui' show PlatformDispatcher;
    
double get devicePixelRatio => PlatformDispatcher.instance.views.first.devicePixelRatio;
```